# Listview not showing on startup but shows after rebuilding/refreshing - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I need some help please. On startup, everything loads except the listview. When I do anything on the page the listview appears. Feels like a refresh/rebuild issue. How do I tell it to refresh the listview? I don't know where to maybe use setState (doesn't work in Scaffold)

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: _buildBar(context),
  body: HouseLayout(),
);} 

class HouseLayout extends StatefulWidget {
@override
  HouseLayoutState createState() {
    return HouseLayoutState();
  }
}

class HouseLayoutState extends State<HouseLayout> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int y = 0;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text(taal.HuisTitle,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 28,
                )),
            backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(61, 147, 243, 1.0)),
        body: Stack(alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft, children: [
          Column(children: [
            Expanded(
                flex: 10,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, indexA) {
                    var kasNaam = kaste[indexA];
                    return Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                        Card(
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(96, 166, 243, 1.0),
                          child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    '$kasNaam',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      IconButton(
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.edit,
                                              color: Colors.white),
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            setState(() {
                                              _editKasDialog(indexA);
                                            });
                                          }),
                                      IconButton(
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.delete,
                                              color: Colors.white),
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            setState(() {
                                              for (int i = 0;
                                                  i < kruideniers.length;
                                                  i++) {
                                                if (kruideniers[i].kas ==
                                                    kaste[indexA]) {
                                                  y++;
                                                }
                                              }
                                              if (y != 0) {
                                                _deleteNotPossibleDialog(y);
                                              }
                                              if (y == 0) {
                                                _deleteKasConfirmDialog(indexA);
                                              }
                                            });
                                          }),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ]),
                        ),
                        _isSearching
                            ? _buildSearchList(context, kasNaam)
                            : _bouKruideniersLys(context, kasNaam),
                      ]),
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: kaste.length,
                )),
            Container(height: 40),
          ]),
          Container(color: Color.fromRGBO(61, 147, 243, 1.0), height: 40),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Stack(children: [
              Container(width: 300, height: 350),
              Positioned(...),
              Positioned(...),
              Positioned(...),
              Positioned(...),
              Positioned(...),
                    Container(width: 5, height: 5),
                    Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                            elevation: 5,
                            shape: CircleBorder(),
                            backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(16, 124, 243, 1.0),
                            child: SizedBox(
                                width: 56,
                                height: 56,
                                child: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart,
                                    size: 35, color: Colors.white)),
                            splashColor: Colors.yellow,
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/shop');
                              });
                            },
                            heroTag: null)),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ]),
          )
        ]));
  }
```

Any help will be great! Thanks

I read kaste list from a txt file:

```
    List<String> kaste = [];

    void readFileH() async {
  final fileH = await findFileH();
  List<String> contents = await fileH.readAsLines();
  String kas;

  for (int i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
    kas = contents[i].substring(0, contents[i].indexOf("#"));
    contents[i] = contents[i].replaceRange(0, contents[i].indexOf("#") + 1, "");
    kaste.add(kas);
  }
  kaste.sort();
}
```

Comment: Please share the related code when you set your kaste list. I think you are not using setState() in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the problem is that the data is null when flutter render the ListView because the data isn't loaded, you need to use a wrap your ListView into a future builder, while the data is loading you can put a image or a circular progress indicator, when the data is loaded you render the elements into a ListView

Comment: Thank you. I will try it

Comment: Put you function like this: Future<void> readFileH ....
Now in the fururebuilder you put the function of above :)

Comment: Sorry it's been a while since I worked on this part of the program. I see that I'm calling the read functions in initState(). If I call them in the build part it repeatedly reads the files. Because it is a nested listview. ''' void initState() { WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(() => readFileK()); WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(() => readFileH()); WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(() => readFileA()); WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(() => readFileW()); super.initState();} '''

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian. The future function was the answer. Just had to get the right place etc. Everything is working now.

Comment: Hi, I'm happy of help you, you can help me choose my answer as the correct 